# How can I choose the second highest value from a list in c#?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list `List<int> myList = new List<int>() { 10, 20, 8, 20, 9, 5, 20, 10 };`, I want to choose the second highest value, which is in this case `10`. I wrote this code and it works, but I wonder if there is something shorter and better.

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>() { 10, 20, 8, 20, 9, 5, 20, 10 };
myList = myList.Distinct().ToList();
var descendingOrder = myList.OrderByDescending(i => i);
var sec = descendingOrder.Skip(1).First();
```

Comment: if by better you mean faster, it can be done in `O(n)` time.

Comment: you may need to define "better" as it could mean many things.

Comment: Maybe just "shorter" will be enough to describe what I want.

Comment: If you want to do it in O(N) time, just foreach over the loop looking for the max and second max values.  That will be cheaper (for a large list) than sorting

Answer (score 9):

You could just stop using intermediate variables and `ToList()`

```
var secondHighest = 
    myList
    .Distinct()
    .OrderByDescending(i => i);
    .Skip(1)
    .First();
```

This will work the same as your version, but only requires one statement instead of three.

I find it a lot easier to read code list this.

Each LINQ method call on it's own line, and no intermediate variables, especially ones that change (`myList` is reassigned, which makes it harder to comprehend).

Comment: The call to `OrderByDescending` will Invoke a sort algorithm. Suddenly an operation that should be **O(N)** is now **O(N * log(N))**

Answer (score 7):

[Dave's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53858570/how-can-i-choose-the-second-highest-value-from-a-list-in-c/53858597#53858597) suggestion to perform all the operations in one pipeline is very good indeed as it avoids:

1. unnecessary intermediate variables
2. eagerly creating new collection objects at intermediate steps
3. reduces clutter.
4. more readable i.e. it's easier to see what's going on

On the other hand, in terms of efficiency, it might be better to perform two passes over the source list instead of "sorting" the entire list only to take the second item.

```
var maximum = myList.Max();
var secondMaximum = myList.Where(x => x < maximum).Max();
```

Comment: Would it be even better to use `myList.Where(x => x < myList.Max()).Max();`?

Comment: @SamW that would also work but I am concerned that it will evaluate the maximum value of the list each time the predicate to `Where` is invoked. whereas this can be avoided with the above aproach.

Comment: Eliminating _unnecessary intermediate variables_ doesn't add very much. Tmp variables often add clarity (and more often add to debuggablility). Tmp variables are usually removed by the JITter, so they cost nothing at runtime (in release  builds)

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd avoid LINQ for this one and just go for a standard "loop over every element, if current is higher than max, push current max to second place, current value to current max"

```
int sec = int.MinValue;
for(int i =0, m= int.MinValue; i <list.Length; i++)
  if(list[i] > m){
    sec = m;
    m = list[i];
  }
```

Your given logic distincts the values so it looks like 20 is not the second highest in your list even though there are three values that are 20. This is achieve here by the >. If I'd used >= then each 20 would roll the variables and it would behave as if non distincted

If you're interested in performance, test it over a list with a few million entries and pick the one that meets your appetite for readability vs speed

Answer (score 0):

It's not LINQ-y, but it's O(N) and easy to read:

```
  public static int TheSecondMax()
  {
      List<int> myList = new List<int>() { 10, 20, 8, 20, 9, 5, 20, 10 };
      int max = int.MinValue;
      int secondMax = int.MinValue;
      foreach (var item in myList)
      {
          if (item > max)
          {
              max = item;
          }

          if (item > secondMax && item < max)
          {
              secondMax = item;
          }
      }

      return secondMax;
  }
```

Comment: How would one find out how efficient a LINQ statement is? I'm curious to see how @Aomine's answer stacks up in terms of efficiency.

Comment: @SamW Build a test, time how long it takes to run (might have to run it a large number of time in a row to get meaningful numbers)

Comment: @MikeH I was talking more along the lines of the limiting factor of the LINQ solution - is it also O(N)?

Comment: @SamW Ahh, I see.  I'm pretty sure it is O(N), but to test you would want to create lists of varying sizes and test how long they take to run.  If it's not O(N) the time will get exponentially longer rather than linearly.

Comment: @SamW Also, make sure your lists are not already sorted to start with!

Comment: A good sort algorithm is typically O(n Log(n)) (i.e., if you have 2n elements in the list it will take you about (2n * log(2n)) / (n * log(n)) times as long to process.  Foreach-ing over a twice as long list will take you twice as long.  See http://bigocheatsheet.com/